# selenium stale element c#

Tags: c#, selenium

```
protected SelectElement GetSelectElement(By selector)
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(c =>
        {
            try
            {
                new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(selector));
                return true;
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(selector));
    }
```

Even with this function I still get stale element on the return line, not sure what else to do to avoid the stale element.

Comment: Are the elements actually present and have not changed? The reason why you get a stale element exception is because the DOM has changed without your WebDriver knowing about it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are doing a `boolean` check but not using it when returning the `SelectElement`. As a result, `return new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(selector));` throws `StaleElementException` by not caring what you have done earlier.

```
protected SelectElement GetSelectElement(By selector)
{
    bool flag = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(c =>
    {
        try
        {
            new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(selector));
            return true;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (flag)
    {
        return new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(selector));

    }
    else
    {
        //something
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Specific to the question code so I had to tweak it a little to make it work in my program but this is a solid example.